# Unable to do automated Amazon search using Selenium IE Driver

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-8, selenium-webdriver

When I tried to perform automated search on amazon.com, It throws exception 'Element Not Found' even thought the element is present. I am trying to access search textbox by its ID.

Following are some observation of it:

- [Amazon search page](http://www.amazon.com/) has proper ID for search components But still Selenium was not able to locate the element, throws exception 'Element Not Found'.
- If you put some delay after loading the Amazon website, Then try to locate the element, throws exception 'Window Not Found'.
- When I tried to get the page source using Selenium Driver, It was not able fetch correct source also. I got the source of the html page which get displayed immediately after IE opened.

I suspect that amazon loads some javascript to prevent automated access, I am not sure.

Any suggestion would be appreciated to resolve this issue.

Please do share your experience if anyone faced such issue before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me ..

```
InternetExplorerDriver d1 = new InternetExplorerDriver();
d1.get("http://www.amazon.com/");
d1.findElementById("twotabsearchtextbox").sendKeys("cheese");
d1.quit;
```

This opens the IE 8 window and types in cheese into the search box.  Note : I am on webdriver 2.25 and have the latest IEDriver downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=IEDriverServer_x64_2.26.2.zip&can=2&q=).

Hope you have set the protected mode to enabled or same for all security zones in your IE settings.

Comment: The problem was with security zones / IE Settings. Thanks for pointing that :)

Comment: For others who may stumble upon this question and answer, please see [this article](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) for a full explanation of why blindly setting the INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS capability (or equivalent for your language binding) in your code is a bad idea. That capability must be set somewhere in your code, as otherwise, an exception would be thrown when executing `new InternetExplorerDriver()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
 driver.get("http://www.amazon.com/");
 driver.findElement (By.id("twotabsearchtextbox").sendKeys("state");
 or
 driver.findElement (By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']").sendKeys("state");
 or
 driver.findElement (By.xpath("//input[@name='field-keywords']").sendKeys("state"); 
 driver.quit;
```